# Dynamically add URL rules to Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I am writing an app in which users will be able to store information that they can specify a REST interface for.  IE, store a list of products at `/<username>/rest/products`.  Since the URLs are obviously not known before hand, I was trying to think of the best way to implement dynamic URL creation in Flask.  The first way I thought of would be to write a catch-all rule, and route the URL from there.  But then I am basically duplicating URL routing capabilities when Flask already has them built-in.  So, I was wondering if it would be a bad idea to use `.add_url_rule()` ([docs here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#application-object), scroll down a bit) to attach them directly to the app.  Is there a specific reason this shouldn't be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every time you execute `add_url_rule()` the internal routing remaps the URL map.  This is neither threadsafe nor fast.  I right now don't understand why you need user specific URL rules to be honest.  It kinda sounds like you actually want user specific applications mounted?

Maybe this is helpful: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/

Comment: I have the same requirement i.e. I'm looking for a way to dynamically add new endpoints to an API built with [Eve](http://python-eve.org) using its `register_resource` method, which calls `add_url_rule` internally. Note that this won't happen for every request, only triggered by a hook when a `POST` to a specific endpoint is received so performance should not be an issue.

Comment: Exactly the same requirement here. Api, that needs adding and removing a new route whenever a PUT request happen at certain route. In my case i'm using flask-restful, but basically is the same.

Comment: It seems I can do this in before_request if I use threading.lock, however, I'm not sure how to stop issues with url_for having the following error: ValueError: list modified during sort ERROR:app:Internal Server Error, list modified during sort

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar requirement for my application where each endpoint `/<SOMEID>/rest/other` for given `SOMEID` should be bounded to a different function. One way to achieve this is keeping a lookup dictionary where values are the function that handle the specific `SOMEID`. For example take a look at this snippet:

```
func_look_up_dict = {...}
@app.route('<SOMEID>/rest/other', methods=['GET'])
def multiple_func_router_endpoint(SOMEID):
    if SOMEID in func_look_up_dict.keys():
        return jsonify({'result' = func_look_up_dict[SOMEID]()}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({'result'='unknown', 'reason'='invalid id in url'}), 404
```

so for this care you don't really need to "dynamically" add url rules, but rather use a url rule with parameter and handle the various cases withing a single function. Another thing to consider is to really think about the use case of such URL endpoint. If `<username>` is a parameter that needs to be passed in, why not to use a url rule such as `/rest/product/<username>` or pass it in as an argument in the GET request? 
Hope that helps.